# npm failed : Failed to parse json

Tags: json, npm

I want to use npm to run my test script in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, it shows the following error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-116-generic        
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "test"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6        
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2        
npm ERR! file /home/parth/Documents/Ethereum/Project/inbox/package.json        
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE         
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! No data, empty input at 1:1
npm ERR! ^        
npm ERR! File: /home/parth/Documents/Ethereum/Project/inbox/package.json        
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.        
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.         
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.         
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
```

My script:

```
{
"name": "inbox",
"version":"1.0.0",
"description":"",
"main":"index.js",
"scripts":{
"test":"mocha"
},
"author":"",
"license":"ISC",
"devDependencies":{
"ganache-cli":"^6.0.3",
"mocha":"^4.0.1",
"sloc":"^0.4.19",
"web3":"^1.0.0-beta.26"
}
}
```

I also had tried to use "npm cache clean" but it didnt work...
Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: An empty file is an **invalid** JSON

Comment: my script was added

Comment: From which directory you launch your script!

Comment: This is my project directory: "~/Documents/Ethereum/Project/inbox$" and under this directory, there is my package.json file. I ran "npm run test" in this dir.

Comment: **npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.**

Comment: My script should be JSON format as I posted. Or does it have any problem? I cant find any problem at all. This made me crazy.

Comment: "test":"mocha"! In your test script you have just `mocha` ? what will it launch as script?

Comment: Yes.. I just tried to re-install mocha again. Then it works! Thanks a lot! However, the error message always confused people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do nothing inside your `test` script! (just tried to re-install mocha!).

```
"scripts":{
"test":"mocha"
}
```

You should edit your **test** script `"test":" Action_to_lunch"`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, I am new in here. Can you tell me how to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run a test and you get the following error:

```
 Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token : in JSON at position 9 while parsing near '"scripts": {
npm ERR!     "test": "mo...'
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Project\test\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
```

Open your package.json and enter:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha"
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that everything in package.json enters inside { ... }.